# Racket Scheme - stream-map issue

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am having a problem implementing stream-map for the purpose of removing newlines from a stream of characters.

Below is my current implementation of remove-newlines:

```
 (define remove-newlines2
  (lambda (str)
    (cond
      ((stream-empty? str) '())
      (else (stream-map (lambda (x)
                          (cond
                            ((equal? x #\newline) (remove x str ))
                            (else '())
                            )) ;procedure
                          str ; stream
  )))))
```

I've toyed around with different implementations. However, it appears that no matter what I do, Racket only recognizes it as a stream, and does nothing further:

```
(remove-newlines2 (file->stream "text-source-file"))
#<stream>
>
```

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the expected behavior, because [`stream-map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-map%29%29) returns a `stream` as its output. To get its contents you have to evaluate or force the result, for instance using [`stream->list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-~3elist%29%29) on the `stream`:

```
(stream->list (remove-newlines2 (file->stream "text-source-file")))
```